# asp.net c# GDI application

Tags: asp.net, gdi

im just going through a tutorial on image creation using GDI on an asp.net page using c#

my code is below

html page code

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Image1.aspx.cs" Inherits="GDI_1.Image1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:Image runat="server" ID="img" ImageUrl="Image1.aspx" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

asp.net page behind code

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;


namespace GDI_1
{
    public partial class Image1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Bitmap image = new Bitmap(300, 50);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image);
            g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, 1, 1, 298, 48);
            Font font = new Font("Impact", 20, FontStyle.Regular);
            g.DrawString("test text", font, Brushes.Yellow, 10, 5);
            image.Save(Response.OutputStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
            g.Dispose();
            image.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

my problem is when i compile it and view the page it is displaying loads of this

GIF89a,2�3f���++3+f+�+�+�UU3UfU�U�U���3�f��������3�f��������3�fՙ������3�f������3333f3�3�3�3+3+33+f3+�3+�3+�3U3U33Uf3U�3U�3U�3�3�33�f3��3��3��3�3�33�f3��3��3��3�3�33�f3ՙ3��3��3�3�33�f3��3��3��ff3fff�f�f�f+f+3f+ff+�f+�f+�fUfU3fUffU�fU�fU�f�f�3f�ff��f��f��f�f�3f�ff��f��f��f�f�3f�ffՙf��f��f�f�3f�ff��f��f����3�f���̙��+�+3�+f�+��+̙

and all before the html tag

thanks

Comment: I have no knowledge in this topic, but for me it looks like your output is the binary representation of your picture. Why? Just open a random .gif with an texteditor. Is your way to present correct?

Comment: fully agree, my answer is why when it shouldnt be

Answer (score 2):

If you are just trying to run this directly within a page then that is what you will get.

To display correctly you need to set it to the source of an image i.e

```
<asp:Image runat="server" ID="img" ImageUrl="ImageBuilder.aspx" />
```

Where ImageBuilder.aspx is a page which contains your code.

**Edit**

What you need to do is have 2 pages.

Image1.aspx contains your image control as you currently have - change the source of the image to Image2.aspx.

Create a new page called Image2.aspx and remove everything from the aspx except the <%@ Page line. Now remove the code from Image1 Page_Load and paste it in to Image2 Page_Load.

Rebuild and try again.

Comment: it is now putting the image on the page, however, I still get all the source binary at the very top of the page. any clues?

Comment: That is a bit weird - can you make sure the aspx for the ImageBuilder page has nothing in it except the <%@ Page line at the top (i.e no HTML or anything) and see if that helps. If not can you edit your answer and show a more complete code listing of what you have?